# What is Toby's Troops in The Office?

Tags: the-office

Throughout the whole series of the Office, while at Toby's desk, a green sign is featured behind him. This sign reads TOBYHANNA in the top left corner, and says Toby's troops on the right hand side. Is this some backstory on Toby that was forgot to be mentioned? What is this, and about when did he found this in relation to the series of The Office?

Answer (score 9):

TobyHanna is a real federal credit union in Scranton, PA. A friend of mine that lives there told me the credit union used to call its members “troops”.

It used to be called TobyHanna ArmyDepot Federal Credit Union but had it’s name changed to TobyHanna Federal Credit Union later on.

It doesn't have anything to do with Toby himself. It's possible maybe Toby is a member of the credit union, and received the sign as a member and liked it for its ironic value, so he displays it at work. That part is just speculation, but still a likely reason he keeps it. It's not really made clear otherwise.

Comment: Turns out there's a [Wikipedia entry for TobyHanna Army Depot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobyhanna_Army_Depot).  Who knew?

Comment: I once went to Tobyhanna, Pennsylvania on a job interview.  According to Wikipedia there is a Tobyhanna Township in Monroe County, PA, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobyhanna_Township,_Monroe_County,_Pennsylvania  and an unincorporated community Tobyhanna in Coolbaugh Township, Monroe County, PA.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobyhanna,_Pennsylvania

Comment: But how does this necessarily relate to Toby in The Office

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Regarding the question you just deleted: I was just about to ask if you could point out those or some specific inconsistencies, that would've helped your post.

Answer (score -2):

@MissouriSpartan and OP:

As someone who lives 30 minutes from Scranton and in Monroe county PA for the last 18 years, It is still called the Tobyhanna Army Depot.

It's an depot for the US military. Toby probably just supports his local military.

Tobyhanna is not in Scranton by the way. It's about 20 minutes away and is its own separate town, and the town is so big that it has a army base.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! I'm afraid I had to tone down your wording somewhat as it was unnecessarily confrontational and rude. It's okay to disagree with answers, but please try and be civil about it, instead of yelling and swearing.